# Limiting the scope of a NamedPipeServerStream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, ipc, named-pipes

I would like to use `NamedPipeServerStream` to do some small IPC between instances of an app. However I only want to target the server if it is on the same Terminal Server Session as the client (If the app is run in a TS-environment).
An idea to achieve this would be to use the SID of the logon user and concat this with the Pipes name. Hover I think this will give problems if the user is loged on from two different locations and it also seems not very neat to me.

Is there a possiblity to give `NamedPipeServerStream` a scope in which it responds to calls and to set this scope so that the RDP-Session builds the border? Or has someone a good idea how to limit the scope/achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit it to one session only you can [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a named mutex within the local namespace to limit its visibility within your session. When a client wants to connect
it can create the same mutex and if it gets as last error code ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS back it knows that within the current session a pipe server is.

You can get the current session number of your process via [ProcessIdToSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you can create a named pipe server with the session id in its name.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
static extern int ProcessIdToSessionId(int pid, ref int session);
```

Addenum:
To get your current Session Id you can simply use Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId instead of the PInvoke signature defined above.

Comment: +1 Thanks, using the session number seems to me a proper way.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no PInvoke signature defined within .Net 2 or 4. You have to use PInvoke

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId seems to do what I need.

Comment: Ahh did miss that one. I have only looked at a method call to ProcessIdToSessionId but the Process class uses NtQuerySystemInformation to gets its data.